# How to fully disable the gnome automounter in ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS?

Tags: usb, nautilus

I want to prevent my usb flash drives from automatically mounting when I am using ubuntu 18.04.3. I tried the command below, but it did not work.

## gconftool-2 --direct \

--config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory \
--type bool \
--set /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount false

## gconftool-2 --direct \

--config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory \
--type bool \
--set /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_autorun_never true

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you are asking? It is sort of confusing, to say the least.

Comment: All etcher is doing is copying the content of the ubuntu/debian install cd onto your flash device. So anything the ubuntu/debian install cd can normally do, this should also be able to do. That said, most modern linux distros auto-mount removable media. If you don't want this behavior you should learn how to turn it off... not change distros.

Comment: @CA Never read anywhere its possible turn off 'automount' on a live-usb or the installed OS that came from live USB. I get the feeling there may be some simple CL to do this...

Comment: You can set up a server from which to boot over the network to install, but it is just easier to copy the install image to e.g. a USB stick and work from there.

Comment: Hddfsck777, what you think you're doing with "@P" and "@CA" isn't working. If you want to reference someone else explicitly you need to use (at least three characters of) their name. For example "@roaima" rather than "@r".

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: It's really not clear what the problem is. You should [edit] the question to provide more detail. See [ask].

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I believe they do not like how `gvfs` mounts USB flash drives (an other devices) connected to the system without user interaction.

Comment: Someone mentioned "dconf editor", but I didn't find a way to use it.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your definitions. Both debian and ubuntu have installers to install them from cd/dvd/usb, those would not normally be "live", but they are bootable (they have to be), and it is possible to do certain tasks from them.

There's nothing resembling automounters running on any of my debian boxes, and (although I never cared for them) I don't think automounters were a thing the last time I tried ubuntu on a desktop.

All that said, I think you may be on a wrong track. I think starting an automounter is something you desktop environment (popular choices include Gnome, KDE, lxde, cinnamon) does, so that's possibly where you have to look.